# If you select 20 people at random. What is the probability that at least one pair of people share the same birthday?

Tags: probability, birthday

If you select 20 people at random. What is the probability that at least one pair of people share the same birthday? (Ignore leap years.)

I was thinking of the total number of possibilities so like (20)^20, for the denominator of the fraction. But I am not sure about this. Also am not too sure about how to do the numerator i.e. the choosing using factorials?

Comment: You better look at the complement problem: no pair has the same birthday.

Comment: How many choices for a birthdate does the first person have?  Does he have 20 choices?  or does he have 365 choices?  How many choices for the second person if we don't care about repetition?  if we do?  How many ways can 20 people have birthdays?  $20^{20}$ or something else?  Maybe something to do with $365$?  As a general suggestion, it is easier to find the probability of the opposite event, in this case all people have different birthdays, and subtract that probability from one.

Comment: The total number of possibilities for their birthdays is $365^{20}$.  The total number of possibilities if the birthdays must be unique is $365! / (365-20)!$.

Comment: $1-\frac{\binom{365}{20}\cdot20!}{365^{20}}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem <=== Birthday Problem in Wikipedia

Comment: See this too: http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/puzzle03.html

Comment: You can find many further duplicates and near-duplicates by searching for "birthday" on this site.